# Migrating computers from LogMeIn to Teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop, automation, remote-access, teamviewer, logmein

I work for a small IT company that currently manages around 500 computers for customers all over North America.   Recently we were notified by LogMeIn that they expected us to pay $49.00 a computer that we want to manage so we have decided to switch from using LogMeIn to using TeamViewer.   We currently have a 14 day trial professional account for TeamViewer - and so far it seems like a great product, but I was wondering if anyone on superuser had any experience migrating large numbers of PCs in varied locations, running everything from Windows XP to Windows 8.1 (and every single OS in between) from LogMeIn to Teamviewer?

Currently, I have added all of our customers to the TeamViewer management interface.   I have been deploying the TV9 Host application by generating a Host download link via the control panel that I set to join a specific customer when a computer accesses a URL associated with the TeamViewer Host download.

I wrote a quick batch script that opens explorer.exe and goes to the URL associated with that client.   I put the batch file on the DC in NETLOGON so it can be easily accessed.

Is there a better way to deploy TeamViewer?    If there is some way to do an unattended install or feed teamviewer command line switches so I do not have to interact with the installer as much?   Having to do this on 500 machines already seems like quite a task.

Also, does anyone know of any way to automate (via Batch or PowerShell) the removal of the LogMeIn Free client from each machine?

Any tips or tricks on making the switch over to be a little less painless would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, we ended up purchasing the Corporate license for TeamViewer and are deploying via MSI.   Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject win32_product -filter "Name LIKE '%logmein%'"

IdentifyingNumber : {36E0F777-19FE-4454-BB2D-84206758EA85}
Name              : LogMeIn
Vendor            : LogMeIn, Inc.
Version           : 4.1.2651
Caption           : LogMeIn

PS> msiexec /x "{36E0F777-19FE-4454-BB2D-84206758EA85}" /quiet /norestart
```

Once you have the IdentifyingNumber for your product, just run the msiexec line against all your target clients to uninstall it.